# Circumcision and the Head of Goliath

Tags: 1-samuel, circumcision

In 1 Samuel 17:46, David taunts the Philistine giant saying, "This day the Lord will deliver you into my hands, and I’ll strike you down and cut off your head." And sure enough, when he defeats the Philistine:

> David ran and stood over him. He took hold of the Philistine’s sword and drew it from the sheath. After he killed him, he cut off his head with the sword.

Peter Leithart traces a head theme in his book A Son to Me through the books of Samuel - Saul being a head taller, the giant losing his head, Absalom having his head caught in the branches of the tree - and ties it back to Genesis 3:15 and the curse of the crushed head pronounced on the serpent.

Recently I was reading [some thoughts on *Sir Gawain and the Green Knight*](http://blog.ayjay.org/sir-gawain-and-the-green-knight-8/), wherein the (non-) decapitation in that story is interpreted as an allusion to circumcision. For some reason it made me wonder if there might be a symbolism of circumcision going on in the 1 Samuel text as well. Is there any basis for seeing such a symbolism in play?

Answer (score 1):

It is, of course, often hard to confirm or rule out various symbolisms in any passage. Occasionally a author will directly explain it (e.g. Revelation 19:8). Most of the time, however, it is left to the savvy reader to deduce. Certainly it is possible to over-interpret a text, reading things from it that the author never intended. That said, most modern commentaries decline to even comment on the second half of 1 Samuel 17:46, so it seems fair to say that thus far over-interpretation has not been the primary danger of the modern reader of this text. One final thought before I begin my argument: it's worth keeping in mind that 1 Samuel is named as one of the "former prophets." There is no doubt a theological undercurrent to what is written. With that in mind, I offer a couple reasons for why such a symbolism may be in play here.

First, the Philistines in the Old Testament are characterized as being uncircumcised. It is in some sense part of their identity. For instance, in Judges 14:3, Samson's parents ask him if there is no one among his people to marry, "that you must go to take a wife from the uncircumcised Philistines. Similarly, in 1 Samuel 14:6, Jonathan can refer to "the garrison of these uncircumcised" without naming them as the Phillistines. Or note the Hebrew parallelism in 2 Samuel 1:20:<sup>1</sup>

```
 Tell it not in Gath, 
     publish it not in the streets of Ashkelon, 
 lest the daughters of the Philistines rejoice, 
     lest the daughters of the uncircumcised exult.
```

Clearly the original audience would have already associated in their mind the Philistine Goliath with being uncircumcised.

Second, David himself frames the contest with reference to circumcision. In 17:36 he says to Saul, "Your servant has struck down both lions and bears, and this uncircumcised Philistine shall be like one of them, for he has defied the armies of the living God." This is made more interesting by the fact that apart from the renewal of the covenenant in Joshua, circumcision is not a major theme in the former prophets.

Third, the head of the champion Goliath functions as the battle trophy to the similar to the trophies David will obtain in the following chapter as the bride-price for his wife Michal: a hundred Philistine foreskins.

Finally, one wonders if Goliath's armor doesn't also play a symbolic role related to circumcision. Leithart notes that Goliath's armor "is given unusually detailed attention."<sup>2</sup> Similarly, the reader's attention is drawn to the fact that David goes into battle without armor. The armorless circumcised David defeats the armored uncircumcised Philistine, and what David claims in addition to the giant's head as a trophy is his armor (17:54).

Supposing, then, that there is an allusion to circumcision in play here, I would interpret it along the lines of the covenent. The covenent is clearly in play within the text - it is what gives David such assurance that the Lord will deliver him. The symbolism may then be to say that those that will not put themselves under the knife will find themselves under the sword.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Holy Bible: English Standard Version. (2016). (2 Sa 1:20). Wheaton, IL: Crossway Bibles.

<sup>2</sup> Leithart, P. J. (2003). A Son to Me: An Exposition of 1 & 2 Samuel (p. 98). Moscow, ID: Canon Press.